Installing newer dig on debian
I need to install new dig (9.20.*) on debian bookworm. How to do it easily?
I tried to manually download BIND source code and build myself, but I keep hitting some autoconf issues.

Cloning the official repo and going by this build instructions actually worked.
https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/blob/main/doc/arm/build.inc.rst
It seems I was cloning some other random repo.
